# Neural Network pruning mechanism

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, torch, activation-function, pruning

I am working on [SqueezeNet pruning](https://gitlab.com/promach/Pruning-CNN/blob/master/SqueezeNet-Pruning) . I have some questions regarding the [pruning code](https://gitlab.com/promach/Pruning-CNN/blob/master/SqueezeNet-Pruning/finetune.py#L85) which is based on the paper : [PRUNING CONVOLUTIONAL NEURAL NETWORKS FOR RESOURCE EFFICIENT INFERENCE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06440.pdf#page=3)

```
def compute_rank(self, grad):
    activation_index = len(self.activations) - self.grad_index - 1
    activation = self.activations[activation_index]
    values = \
        torch.sum((activation * grad), dim = 0, keepdim=True).\
            sum(dim=2, keepdim=True).sum(dim=3, keepdim=True)[0, :, 0, 0].data

    values = \
        values / (activation.size(0) * activation.size(2) * activation.size(3))

    if activation_index not in self.filter_ranks:
        self.filter_ranks[activation_index] = \
            torch.FloatTensor(activation.size(1)).zero_().cuda()

    self.filter_ranks[activation_index] += values
    self.grad_index += 1
```

1) Why '*values*' uses only in_height (2) and in_width (3) of the activation ? What about in_channels (1) ?

2) Why does *filter_ranks[activation_index]* depend on in_channels (1) only ?

3) Why activation multiplied with gradient ? and why sum them up ?

Answer (score 0):

> Large activation indicates that this filter provides important
>   features.
>
> Large grad shows that this filter is sensitive to different types of
>   input
>
> Filters with large activation and large grad are important and not removed
>
> Sum is because only the entire filter can be removed

This is an educated guess for question 3)

Please correct me if wrong.